# ASP.NET Core 5 - Forms with dynamic number of fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm doing a Web Pages project in ASP.NET Core 5, and I ran into following problem.
My model looks like this

```
  public class Performance
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Dates { get; set; }
        public bool DatesRange { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public Venue Venue { get; set; }

    }
```

Now, in the form, I would like to have input fields for all the fields of Performance model, *except* Dates. The idea is that a single performance can have one, or many dates, so the user will have a possibility of adding additional rows in the form, as many as needed, when creating a new performance.

What I would like to do, but don't know how, is process the binding of the submitted data manually, so I can parse all the submitted dates and convert them into a single string for saving in the database. I'm not sure how, or rather, *where* to do that, though, since the first thing that triggers after hitting submit button is this

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Performance.Add(Performance);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

and the data submitted is already bound to the model. Any form fields that do not correspond to the model are ignored. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried just adding multiple fields with the name `date`? If you do, I _believe_ the model binder will bind them as a comma-delimited list here. So if you have e.g. `?date=2020-12-24&date=1820-12-10` then your `Dates` field _should_ end up with a value of `2020-12-24,1820-12-10`. That said, the textbook solution here would be to make `Dates` a collection and then name your fields in accordance to [the collection conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#collections).

Comment: As an alternative, you can always perform some manual binding prior to calling `ModelState.IsValid` by pulling the values yourself using the `Controller.Request` property, and then setting them to your model manually. That's a quick and easy way of handling one-off model binding exceptions without implementing a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `asp-page-handler` to make another request from the inside form of your razor pages. Also, you need to define Dates as `List<string>` your `Performance` model will look like

In your razor page, you need to set up multiple post

```
<form method="post">
<input asp-for="perf.Date" value="Date" />
<button asp-page-handler="Date">Add</button>
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Date</td>
    </th>
    @if (Model.Dates != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Dates.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.Dates[i] @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Dates[i])</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
   
    
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

`cshtml.cs` file will be following signatures. `OnPostDate` will handle separate post to add date. 'OnPost' will handle full model posting.

```
  [BindProperty] public Performance perf { get; set; }
    [BindProperty] public List<string> Dates { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        perf = new Performance();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        foreach (string dt in Dates)
        {    
            perf.Date = dt;
            _context.Performance.Add(Performance);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");       
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostDate()
    {
        if (Dates.Count == 0)
        {
            Dates = new List<string>();
            Dates.Add(perf.Date);
        }
        else
        {
            Dates.Add(perf.Date);
        }

        
        return Page();
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]